# WordPress Filter Text in localized scripts

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, localization

The WooCommerce bookings extension has the following for adding some text to the calendar label:

```
<?php 
        $booking_form_params = array(
            'ajax_url'                   => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'i18n_date_unavailable'      => __( 'This date is unavailable', 'woocommerce-bookings' ),
            'i18n_date_fully_booked'     => __( 'This date is fully booked and unavailable', 'woocommerce-bookings' ),
            'i18n_date_partially_booked' => __( 'This date is partially booked - but bookings still remain', 'woocommerce-bookings' ),
            'i18n_date_available'        => __( 'This date is available', 'woocommerce-bookings' ),
            'i18n_start_date'            => __( 'Choose a Start Date', 'woocommerce-bookings' ),
            'i18n_end_date'              => __( 'Choose an End Date', 'woocommerce-bookings' ),
            'i18n_dates'                 => __( 'Dates', 'woocommerce-bookings' ),
            'i18n_choose_options'        => __( 'Please select the options for your booking above first', 'woocommerce-bookings' ),
        );

        wp_localize_script( 'wc-bookings-booking-form', 'booking_form_params', apply_filters( 'booking_form_params', $booking_form_params ) );
?>
```

I'd like to modify the start and end dates but I'm not sure how to add those filters. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  In case it helps anyone...

```
add_filter( 'booking_form_params', 'checkin_checkout' );
function checkin_checkout( $labels ) {

    foreach ( $labels as $key => $label ) {
        if ( $key == 'i18n_start_date' ) {
            $labels[$key] = 'Please choose a check-in date';
        }
        if ( $key == 'i18n_end_date' ) {
            $labels[$key] = 'Please choose a check-out date';
        }
    }

    return $labels;

}
```